# What would probably happen when the Flying Ford Anglia runs out of fuel?

Tags: harry-potter

The Flying Ford Anglia only appears in Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets. Mr. Weasley had enchanted it to fly, become invisible and to be able to fit in eight people. It also has some intelligence which can be gauged from the fact that the car came to Harry's and Ron's rescue in the book. And we also know that the Forbidden Forest had turned the car wild and it had taken to roaming the forest.

Now keeping these things in mind, I have two questions.

1. What would happen if the car runs out of fuel?
2. Does the car actually need fuel?

Comment: I would say it does not need fuel, i probably has been driving around in the Forbidden Forest when it saves Harry and Ron. Don't know any exact dates, but certainly a few months have passed between the crash against the Whomping Willow in september and their trip to Aragorn.

Comment: @ThomasDB - the huge scary spidery monstrosity is named **Aragog**. If you call it Aragorn, Tolkien's spirit will come and haunt u at night..

Comment: I don't think it's running because of fuel.It's simply magic !!

Comment: "Never trust anything that can think for itself if you can't see where it keeps its brain."  Wonder whether Arthur was thinking of his car when he said this?

Comment: the fact that the car was running continuously for mulitpul months leads me to believe the car is running on magic.

Comment: A wizard did it!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Ford Anglia's petrol tank is only around [30litres](http://www.fordanglia105eownersclub.co.uk/technical/technical-information/general-specifications/anglia-105e/). We don't know the exact location of Hogwarts, but we know it's in [Scotland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hogwarts), travelling from London to Scotland (even just the border) is over 300 miles.
I'd suggest that unless Arthur Weasley had magically increased the size of the fuel tank, then the car would have ran out on route, strongly suggesting that it doesn't run on petrol.

Edit:

> Harry moved back into the shadows next to Hedwig, who seemed to have realized how important this was and kept still and silent. **The car revved louder and louder** and suddenly, with a crunching noise, the bars were pulled clean out of the window as Fred drove straight up in the air.

Chamber of Secrets: The Burrow

> Ron put his foot on the accelerator and drove them upward again, but as he did so, the engine began to whine

Chamber of Secrets: The Whomping Willow

This shows that the engine is still in use and used for power during flight mode, so what ever normally powers the engine of this Anglia powers it during flight mode also.

Comment: I don't know... what kind of fuel economy can you get when you don't have to turn the wheels for most of the trip? That's the bulk of the work an engine does on a normal car, but then again the propulsion isn't really explained in this case. I don't really think it uses petrol either, but I also don't think this is all that great an argument.

Comment: @Geobits - Agreed. There's no special indication to assume that it's using petrol in "flight mode".

Comment: @Ben I got to agree with you. I was confused about it myself.

Comment: I have a theory, it could be wrong. Maybe the tank was magically enlarged or there was spell to increase the quantity of fuel as it went down in the tank.

Answer (score 12):

I do not believe the car runs on petrol. Arthur Weasley is intrigued by the Muggle world but does not seem highly capable of functioning within its daily comings and goings of using Muggle money to purchase fuel for his flying car, or maintaining said car when it's not in use. I believe that he enchanted the car to run off of magic. Magic is treated like a never ending resource. It's never even hinted at that one could run out of magic. If the car was enchanted by Arthur Weasley to run off of magic it would continue to run until the end of Mr. Weasley's lifetime, for as we know when Lily's fish disappeared and the freezing spell put on Harry by Dumbledore both ended at their deaths.

When Arthur does die the car will cease to run and the "soul" of the wild car will pass on.

Comment: That would certainly seem to not be the case for *all* spells, for example, the anti-muggle enchantments on Hogwarts don't seem to go away when whomever casted them dies.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: Got any citations saying that once put up, the anti-muggle spells remain? Or that they've never been cast more than once on Hogwarts (or other wizarding building)?

Comment: @KyleKanos No, but given that Hermione mentions that they are in "Hogwarts, a History" I would think its fair to assume that they've been around longer than Dumbledore, and we don't see a mad dash to put them back up after his death.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET It could simply be that more than one wizard was involved in casting that spell, and that new wizards frequently add their own magic to the maintenance of the spell. That way, unless all the wizards currently maintaining the spell died at once, the spell would remain.

Comment: @Ajedi32 True. Another good example of "permanent" spells *could* be the items in Sirius's home. IIRC many were hexed (which they had to find and deal with in OotP). Such spells would have been cast by his dead mother, with no one maintaining them. I can't prove it, but the books certainly seem to indicate there is magic that lives beyond death.

Comment: @LuenDZ and Wikis as Ben pointed out below, the engine was being used during the flight. It could be that Mr. Weasley magically increase the size of the fuel tank or he used magic to regenerate fuel inside the tank.